# don't show pop-up again if it closed using javascript

Tags: javascript

How can I stop showing pop-up after clicking on close button?

This is my pop-up function, it opens after scrolling to 1300px of page.

```
 $(document).scroll(function() {
    var y = $(this).scrollTop();
    if (y > 1300) {
        $('.popup').fadeIn();
    } 

});
```

but when I closed it , it opend again

this is my button fun

```
function closePopup(){
document.getElementById('popup').style.display = 'none';
}
```

++ this is my button

```
<button  type="button" class="close" id="close-popup" onclick="closePopup()"  aria-label="Close">
 <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a boolean control when it's clicked

```
let popupClosed = false;

function closePopup() {
    document.getElementById('popup').style.display = 'none';
    popupClosed = true;
}

$(document).scroll(function() {
    var y = $(this).scrollTop();
    if (y > 1300 && !popupClosed) {
        $('.popup').fadeIn();
    } 

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a way to control when the popup was opened for the first time (or closed).

```
 $(document).scroll(function() {
    let y = $(this).scrollTop(),
        popup = $('.popup')
    if (y > 1300 && ! popup.data('opened')) {
        popup.data('opened', true)
        popup.fadeIn();
    } 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I replaced your scroll height detection with a button. Just call `$('.popup').popupShow()` whenever you scroll past 1,300 pixels.

Make sure you call `$('.popup').popup(options)` with the appropriate close/open callbacks.

Once you close the popup for the first time, a data attribute of `doNotOpen` will be set to `true`. Subsequent open attempts will not be allowed, because the `open` callback checks for the presence of that `doNotOpen` data value.

```js
function main() {
  $('.popup').popup({
    title: 'Popup Test',
    open: function() {
      return !this.data('doNotOpen'); // type boolean
    },
    close: function() {
      this.data('doNotOpen', true);
    }
  });

  $('.show-btn').on('click', function() {
    $('.popup').popupShow();
  });
}

/**
 * @name   flex-popup.jquery.js
 * @date   2021-03-03
 * @author Mr. Polywhirl
 *
 * Callback when opening a popup.
 * @callback openCallback
 * @return {boolean} whether to show the popup
 *
 * Callback when closing a popup.
 * @callback closeCallback
 */
(function($) {
  var defaultOptions = {
    title: null,
    content: null
  };

  var setAndDelete = function($el, prop, props) {
    if (props[prop]) {
      $el.html(props[prop]);
      delete props[prop];
    }
  };

  /**
   * @param {string} title
   * @param {string} content
   * @param {options.openCallback} open
   * @param {options.closeCallback} close
   */
  $.fn.popup = function(options) {
    var opts = $.extend(true, {}, defaultOptions, options);
    if (this.is(':empty')) this.popupCreate();
    this.find('.popup-close').on('click', function() {
      $(this).closest('.popup').popupHide();
    });
    setAndDelete(this.find('.popup-header-title'), 'title', opts);
    setAndDelete(this.find('.popup-content'), 'content', opts);
    return this.data(opts).css('display', 'flex').hide();
  };

  $.fn.popupCreate = function() {
    return this
      .append($('<div>').addClass('popup-header')
        .append($('<div>').addClass('popup-header-title'))
        .append($('<div>').addClass('popup-close')))
      .append($('<div>').addClass('popup-content'));
  };

  $.fn.popupShow = function() {
    if (this.is(':hidden') && (!this.data('open') || this.data('open').call(this))) {
      if (this.data('open')) this.data('open').call(this);
      return this.fadeIn();
    } else {
      if (this.is(':hidden')) {
        console.log('Not allowed!');
      }
    }
  };

  $.fn.popupHide = function() {
    if (!this.is(':hidden')) {
      if (this.data('close')) this.data('close').call(this);
      return this.fadeOut();
    }
  };
})(jQuery);

main();
```

```css
:root {
  --popup-background: #AAA;
  --popup-header-background: #777;
  --popup-content-background: #AAA;
  --popup-border-color: #555;
  --popup-close-color: #BBB;
  --popup-close-hover-color: #DDD;
}

body {
  background: #222;
}

.popup {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: absolute;
  top: 25vh;
  left: 25vw;
  width: 50vw;
  height: 50vh;
  z-index: 1000;
  background: var(--popup-background);
  border: thin solid var(--popup-border-color);
}

.popup>.popup-header {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  background: var(--popup-header-background);
  padding: 0.25em 0.5em;
}

.popup .popup-header-title {
  flex: 1;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.popup .popup-close {
  font-size: 2em;
  line-height: 1em;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: var(--popup-close-color);
}

.popup .popup-close:hover {
  color: var(--popup-close-hover-color);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.popup .popup-close::after {
  content: '\00D7';
}

.popup>.popup-content {
  background: var(--popup-content-background);
  flex: 1;
  padding: 0.25em 0.5em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="popup">
  <div class="popup-header">
    <div class="popup-header-title">Replace this</div>
    <div class="popup-close"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="popup-content">
    <h1>Content heading</h1>
    <p>Content description here.</p>
  </div>
</div>
<button class="show-btn">Show Popup</button>
```

**Note:** Here is a mirror on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MrPolywhirl/rdLzhupx/).